# Чтения большого количества файлов маленького размера. Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

Есть очень много json файлов небольшого размера(20-40Кб),более 1 миллиона.Из всех из них выгружаются определенные "строки" и после этого экспортируются в CSV. 
Делал двумя способами:

1:

```
foreach($file in $all_content.name)
{
    $json = Get-Content -Path $json_path$file
    $json_decode = ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $json
    $json_result = $json_decode.response | Select-Object -Property id | Export-Csv $csv_output -Append -Delimiter ";" -NoTypeInformation
}
```

2:

```
foreach($file in $all_content.name)
    {
        $json = Get-Content -Path $json_path$file
        $json_decode = ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $json
        $json_result = $json_decode.response | Select-Object -Property id
        $JSON_TO_CSV += $json_result
    }
Export-Csv $csv_output -Append -Delimiter ";" -NoTypeInformation
```

И тот и другой способ работают слишком медленно. Подозреваю, что это из за частых операций "открытия/чтения/закрытия" каждого файла. Есть ли способ как то ускорить этот процесс, используя средства powershell?

Comment: А структура JSON не допускает простую их конкатенацию в один файл? тупо влоб `Get-Content *.json` ?

Answer (score 1):

Да, можно распараллелить вычисления. можно использовать разные инструменты, можно через встроенные job'ы или через обертки к ним. Например, [Invoke-Parallel](https://github.com/RamblingCookieMonster/Invoke-Parallel).

Мне больше всего нравится [SplitPipeline](https://github.com/nightroman/SplitPipeline). Он распараллеливает то, что подано ему на вход конвеера. Его создавали как "параллельный foreach-object". К тому же у него очень полезеный -verbose режим. Рекомендую.

Для вашего примера должно быть что-то вроде:

```
$json_result = $all_content.name | Split-Pipeline {
    $json = Get-Content -Path $json_path$_
    $json_decode = ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $json
    $json_decode.response | Select-Object -Property id | Export-Csv $csv_output -Append -Delimiter ";" -NoTypeInformation
}
```

Сразу надо оговориться, что все распараллеливатели усложняют отладку, поскольку выполняют свой scriptblock в отдельном runSpace.